# Find $E[(2+X)^2]$

Tags: probability

Given $E(X)=1, Var(X)=5$. Find $E[(2+X)^2]$.

I have two approaches to solve the problem, but they're not giving the same result.

First:

$E[(2+X)^2]=E(4+4X+X^2)=E(4)+4E(X)+E(X^2)=4+4+[Var(X)+E^2(X)]=4+4+(5+1)=14$

Second:

$E[(2+X)^2]=E[(3+X-1)^2]=Var(3+X)=Var(X)=5$

Which is wrong and what mistake did I make?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's probably the second

Comment: It should have been $E(3+X)$ not $1$

Comment: Why is $E[(3+X-1)^2]$ the same as $\operatorname{var}(3+X)$? Since $E[3+X] = 4$, $\operatorname{var}(3+X) = E[(3+X-4)^2]$, no?

Comment: @DilipSarwate yeah, I noticed after I had posted the question :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You second approach would only work if $Y = 3+X$ was a random variable with expectation $1$, which is false.

Answer (score 2):

The second is wrong. The expectation of $(3+X-1)^2$ is not the variance of $X$. But you could expand to $E[9+6(X-1)+(X-1)^2]$, which is $9+0+5$. So the **idea** can be used.